# The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (Oracle)

Tags: sql, oracle

I was using SQL Developer, and today, when I try to start the database I find the error above on tittle, and I don't know why.

The code of lsnrctl status is this:

```
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=IPC)(KEY=EXTPROC1)))
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener                                                                                               
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error                                                                                    
TNS-00511: No listener                                                                                                   
64-bit Windows Error: 2: No such file or directory                                                                   
Connecting to (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=DESKTOP-7AC259Q)
(PORT=1521)))T
TNS-12541: TNS:no listener                                                                                               
TNS-12560: TNS:protocol adapter error                                                                                    
TNS-00511: No listener                                                                                                   
64-bit Windows Error: 61: Unknown error
```

The code of my file tnsnames.ora is this:

```
LISTENER XE =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP) (HOST = localhost) (PORT = 1521))

XE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-7AC259Q)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = XE)
    )
  )

EXTPROC_CONNECTION_DATA =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SID = PLSExtProc)
      (PRESENTATION = RO)
    )
  )

ORACLR_CONNECTION_DATA = 
  (DESCRIPTION = 
    (ADDRESS_LIST = 
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1)) 
    ) 
    (CONNECT_DATA = 
      (SID = CLRExtProc) 
      (PRESENTATION = RO) 
    ) 
  )
```

And the code of the file listener.ora is this:

```
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = PLSExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = CLRExtProc)
      (ORACLE_HOME = C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server)
      (PROGRAM = extproc)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = IPC)(KEY = EXTPROC1))
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = DESKTOP-7AC259Q)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

DEFAULT_SERVICE_LISTENER = (XE)
```

I'm quite new on this so I really don't know what can be happens.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Looks like your listener is not started.  Assuming this is on Windows, open your services.msc  control panel and look at the services that start with 'oracle'.